# Salesforce formula to get last day of previous month after one year

Tags: validation-rule, date

I have validation rule which will throw if the selected date is not last day of previous month after one year

Example - today is Oct 1,2021 then my validation should fire if selected date is not Sept 30,2022
Below is my validation rule but it is not firing. What i am missing?

Edate__c != DATE(YEAR(today()) +1, MONTH(today()) + 1, 1) - 1

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your month math is incorrect

Partially evaluating `DATE(YEAR(today()) +1, MONTH(today()) + 1, 1) - 1`, you'd get
`DATE(2022, 11, 1)` (i.e. 1st of November, 2022)

`MONTH(today()) + 1` should be `MONTH(today()) - 1`

Beyond that, you haven't provided a lot of information to work from.

If this is the entire validation rule, then you'd run into issues trying to make changes to any existing records. You'd need to update `Edate__c` for every record you want to change on every day you want to make a change (which my gut says is likely not what you want to have happen).

Comment: This is the only validation rule i have.  I did change MONTH(today()) - 1 but still no luck.

Comment: @sfdcdeveloper To emphasis the last point, use `AND( ISCHANGED(Edate__c), ...` to make sure the validation rule only checks when required

Comment: I have added ISCHANGED but still my validation rule is not firing correctly